# Understanding the behavior of a self-join on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've inherited the following code (only the first block), but do not understand the differences between

```
UPDATE Contact2 
SET Contact2.gbs_contactid = Contact1.gbs_contactId 
FROM gbs_sourcecontact Contact2 
INNER JOIN gbs_sourcecontact Contact1 
ON Contact1.gbs_sourcecontactid = '90BFC45B-8C75-4054-89D0-5400B225108C' 
WHERE Contact2.gbs_sourcecontactid =' E83C4FF3-4298-4CF3-8718-6CF987CE5803'
```

and

```
UPDATE Contact2 
SET Contact2.gbs_contactid = Contact1.gbs_contactId 
FROM gbs_sourcecontact Contact2 
INNER JOIN gbs_sourcecontact Contact1 
ON Contact1.gbs_sourcecontactid = '90BFC45B-8C75-4054-89D0-5400B225108C' 
AND Contact2.gbs_sourcecontactid =' E83C4FF3-4298-4CF3-8718-6CF987CE5803'
```

and

```
UPDATE Contact2 
SET Contact2.gbs_contactid = Contact1.gbs_contactId 
FROM gbs_sourcecontact Contact2 
INNER JOIN gbs_sourcecontact Contact1 
ON Contact2.gbs_sourcecontactid =' E83C4FF3-4298-4CF3-8718-6CF987CE5803'
WHERE Contact1.gbs_sourcecontactid = '90BFC45B-8C75-4054-89D0-5400B225108C'
```

I'm understanding the concept of inner joins; however, in this specific case I do not understand the behavior of what happens when switching the `ON/WHERE` clauses.

**How will switching the ON/WHERE clauses affect the results?**

Comment: Please look @Ricardo answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154227/whats-the-difference-between-filtering-in-the-where-clause-compared-to-the-on-c/19160557#19160557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switching of the conditions between the `on` and `where` clauses doesn't affect results for an inner join (see caveat below).  These "join"s are confusing, because there is no real link between the tables.  You are just choosing (presumably) single rows from the table and matching them up.

I would be inclined to write the join in the second fashion, with both conditions in the `on` clause.  Mixing conditions in the `on` and `where` clauses leads to confusion -- and questions such as yours.

Caveat:  If there are multiple matches in `Contact1`, then one of the values is chosen for the update (a value from an arbitrary matching row).  The placement of the conditions in the `on` clause versus `where` clause probably doesn't affect the execution plan.  But, you never know.  There could be small differences that would result in different updates in this case.